# What is the verb describing your action when you hold your breath and endeavor to do something?

Tags: word-request

Suppose you are trying to lift a very heavy thing. You hold your breath and concentrate on lifting it with all your might.
Or suppose you are trying to relieve constipation ... ;-)

Is there an English verb to describe it?

Remark:
Holding your breath is the key.

Comment: Though it primarily refers to a woman in labor, you might consider "bear down".

Comment: Is there a word for this in your native language? You might mention it, someone might recognize it and find a good translation.

Comment: @CowperKettle Yes. いきむ

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the word *strain*. At the moment, I am unable to find a definition that explicitly includes "holding your breath", but at the very least I believe it is implied. It is also included as a symptom of constipation on [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/understanding-constipation-symptoms).

One would also *strain* while trying to lift heavy objects.

---

I find definitions like this

> [strain](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/strain)
>    1 [with object] Force (a part of one’s body or oneself) to make a strenuous or unusually great effort:

It is not explicit about the "holding your breath".

I found another case where it is used with boxes:

> If you have to strain to carry the load, it's too heavy. [[1.]](http://familydoctor.org/familydoctor/en/prevention-wellness/staying-healthy/first-aid/lifting-safety-tips-to-help-prevent-back-injuries.html).

Here are a few images I got from googling "straining":

[image: Man's face]
[image: Male weight lifter]

Answer (score -2):

Valsalva Maneuver- Forced exhalation against a closed rima glottidis as may occur during periods of staining while defecating... meaning holding your breath while pushing out poop

Comment: I think this might actually be accurate, but it would benefit from a reference. Also, OP was looking for a verb.

Comment: @Max It doesn't appear to be accurate... [Wikipedia says it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valsalva_maneuver) "is performed by moderately forceful attempted exhalation against a closed airway, usually done by closing one's mouth, pinching one's nose shut while pressing out as if blowing up a balloon." It has nothing to do with pooping.

Comment: @ColleenV Yeah, I'm no expert, but when I took a look at the page, I thought maybe it was possibly the same or similar. The page does go on to talk about weight-lifting and "complications due to defecation". But in any case, this answer could benefit from including a source to give it some credibility.